# filter pgfplots data more than once (e.g. with discard if)

Tags: pgfplots

I want to filter a dat file more than once (i.e., filter on multiple columns), and the [usual solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178629/how-to-read-a-specific-portion-of-a-data-file-in-pgfplots) with "discard if" and "discard if not" doesn't seem to work.

I.e., the following (were file.dat has a column called k) should have empty output, and it doesn't.

```
\addplot[discard if not={k}{3}, discard if={k}{3}]
        table [x=A,  y=B]
        {file.dat};
```

Here is an MWE, including the alternative discard if code given in one of the answers.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}%
% \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,graphicx,array,tabularx,url,enumerate,rotating,fancyvrb,longtable, units,mathabx}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
  discard if/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
      \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
      \edef\tempb{#2}
      \ifx\tempa\tempb
      \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
      \fi
    }
  },
  discard if not/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
      \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
      \edef\tempb{#2}
      \ifx\tempa\tempb
      \else
      \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
      \fi
    }
  }
}

% \pgfplotsset{
%     discard if/.style 2 args={
%         x filter/.code={
%             \ifnum\thisrow{#1}=#2
%                 \def\pgfmathresult{nan}
%             \else
%             \fi
%         }
%     }
%   }
% \pgfplotsset{
%     discard if not/.style 2 args={
%         x filter/.code={
%             \ifnum\thisrow{#1}=#2
%             \else
%                 \def\pgfmathresult{nan}
%             \fi
%         }
%     }
%   }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
\addplot[blue,mark=o,discard if not={k}{3}, discard if={k}{3}] table [x=n,  y=A]{    n A k

1 3 3
2 4 3
3 2 3
1 3 2
1 3 2
1 3 2
};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
\addplot[black,mark=o, discard if={k}{3}] table [x=n,  y=A]{
n A k
1 3 3
2 4 3
3 2 3
1 3 2
1 3 2
1 3 2
};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
\addplot[red,mark=o,discard if not={k}{3}] table [x=n,  y=A]{
n A k
1 3 3
2 4 3
3 2 3
1 3 2
1 3 2
1 3 2
};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to apply multiple filters in pgfplots or should I just cut the .dat files up a little more before-hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter the data more than once by adapting the code (which was originally posted in an answer to [Is it possible to change the color of a single bar when the bar plot is based on symbolic values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on) and [Different color for individual bar in bar chart & adding bar labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80012/2552)) slightly, using `x filter/.append code` instead of `x filter/.code`:

*For filtering on a symbolic column:*

```
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.append code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.append code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}
```

*For filtering on a numerical column:*

```
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.append code={
            \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.append code={
            \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aha!  I have been using this one in another file but I thought the tempa and tempb were part of a tex.se MWE so I didn't test it.  Will try it out now.

Comment: This didn't work when I tested it, so I updated (in 5 min) the question with the MWE

Comment: @Alejandro: To filter on numerical data, you should use a slightly different variant of `discard if` and `discard if not`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Perfect.  It was the .append that was needed.  First part works for my "numerical" data too (I don't know how LaTeX is interpreting it).

Answer (score 1):

For certain plots, such as `hist` (for histograms),
 using `x filter` doesn't work as expected.
This is because `x filter` (and `y filter` etc.) are applied to the resulting intervals,
 after the data has been counted.
To filter this sort of data, one can use `y expr` and `unbounded coords=discard`.

For numeric:

```
\addplot[hist,
    unbounded coords=discard,% nan means ignore
    filter discard warning=false,% no spam
] table [
    y expr={\thisrow{k} == 3 ? \thisrow{A} : nan}
] {file.dat};
```

For symbolic (need a helper macro from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415138/conditional-tests-on-string-variables-in-tikzmath-library)):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\strequal}[2]{\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}==0}
\makeatother

\addplot[hist,
    unbounded coords=discard,% nan means ignore
    filter discard warning=false,% no spam
] table [
    y expr={\strequal{\thisrow{k}}{TM} ? \thisrow{A} : nan}
] {file.dat};
```

Also, `y filter` etc. operate pretty late in the process,
 after any transformations such as applying log scaling, so one should use `rawy`
 in filters or use the `y expr` method above if you are directly filtering y values.