# pgfplots and multiple rows

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a CSV file such as:

```
name,threads,time,standard dev <= columns meaning
data1,1,1.12, 0.007
data1,2,0.6, 0.0030
data1,4,0.6, 0.0031
other,1,6,0.01
other,2,3,0.003
other,4,3,0.003
```

I would like to create a chart that get all rows with the same col1( i.e, with "data1") and use the col 2 as x-axis, and col3 as y-axis. The same with other. I should end up with a chart with two lines, one for data1, and the second for other, both with 3 points.

Is it possible with pgfplots? if not, any suggestion you can point?
thank you

Comment: You can use pgfplotstable to edit the csv into something pgfplots can use, but it won't be easy.  It might even be easier to construct lists of coordinates using \pgfplotstablegetelem one element at a time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to review our [tour].  With questions like this, it helps if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you mean something like

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
name,threads,time,standard dev <= columns meaning
data1,1,1.12,0.007
data1,2,0.6,0.0030
data1,4,0.6,0.0031
other,1,6,0.01
other,2,3,0.003
other,4,3,0.003
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % borrowed styles from Jake's answer at
    % <http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301991/95441>
    \pgfplotsset{
        % filter symbolic values
        discard if not symbolic/.style 2 args={
            % suppress LOG messages about the filtered points
            filter discard warning=false,
            x filter/.append code={
                \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
                \edef\tempb{#2}
                \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \else
                    \def\pgfmathresult{NaN}
                \fi
            },
        },
%        % filter numerical values
%        % (not needed here, but just for completeness)
%        discard if not/.style 2 args={
%            % suppress LOG messages about the filtered points
%            filter discard warning=false,
%            x filter/.append code={
%                \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
%                \else
%                    \def\pgfmathresult{NaN}
%                \fi
%            },
%        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \i in {
                data1,
                other%
            } {
                \addplot+ [
                    discard if not symbolic={name}{\i},
                ] table [
                    col sep=comma,
                    x=threads,
                    y=time,
                ] {data.csv};
                    \addlegendentryexpanded{\i}
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]