# Grouped bar chart in pgfplots from file selecting certain rows

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, graphs

I want to create a bar chart from the following data, using the column `difficulty` to select rows from `kappa`.

I hope to avoid having to type out the contents of the csv file in a series of add plot statements

Can one use the meta variable as follows?

```
\begin{axis}[ybar]

 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
    major grid style={draw=white},axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=right,symbolic x coords={
       Human-Human,Human-Tak,Human-Gold Standard, Tak-Gold Standard},]
    \addplot table[x=type, y=kappa, meta=difficulty=0]{combined-kappas.csv};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=kappa, meta=difficulty=1]{combined-kappas.csv};
    \addplot table[x=type, y=kappa, meta=difficulty=2]{combined-kappas.csv};
\end{axis}
```

CSV Data:

```
r1,r2,type,kappa,difficulty
Alex,Tak,Human-Human,0.9878019029031471,0
Alex,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.6199032480995161,0
Alex,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,1,0
Tak,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.6081143384047948,0
Tak,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.9878019029031471,0
Intended,Inferred,Tak-Gold Standard,0.6199032480995161,0
Alex,Tak,Human-Human, 0.791208791208791,1
Alex,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.306901088386556,1
Alex,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.844389844389844,1
Tak,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.245305729417429,1
Tak,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.757327238504975,1
Intended,Inferred,Tak-Gold Standard,0.337421837421837,1
Alex,Tak,Human-Human,0.547137761168677,2
Alex,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.137205030380104,2
Alex,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.262046204620462,2
Tak,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.137288621381485,2
Tak,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.280682000965096,2
Intended,Inferred,Tak-Gold Standard,0.097688926697859,2
```

Intended output:
[image]

Comment: So you are searching for something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352667/95441?

Comment: @mac389 Please add a compilable snippet.

Comment: @StefanPinnow That example close. It selects single rows. It doesn't select multiple rows based on a column value. I like the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer to [your comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482776/grouped-bar-chart-in-pgfplots-from-file-selecting-certain-rows#comment1220441_482776):
I think the linked answer in *my* comment *is* what you are searching for. But there is *one* remaining problem that is, that you have multiple entries for one bar sometimes which results in multiple bars plotted. In your image there is some kind of error bar given to the bars.

The error bars can also be given to bars, but of course for that you need to modify your CSV file accordingly.

(Please note that this answer is just to prove that this in principle is what you are searching for and thus the resulting image does not look very nice.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\begin{filecontents*}{combined-kappas.csv}
r1,r2,type,kappa,difficulty
Alex,Tak,Human-Human,0.9878019029031471,0
Alex,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.6199032480995161,0
Alex,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,1,0
Tak,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.6081143384047948,0
Tak,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.9878019029031471,0
Intended,Inferred,Tak-Gold Standard,0.6199032480995161,0
Alex,Tak,Human-Human, 0.791208791208791,1
Alex,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.306901088386556,1
Alex,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.844389844389844,1
Tak,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.245305729417429,1
Tak,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.757327238504975,1
Intended,Inferred,Tak-Gold Standard,0.337421837421837,1
Alex,Tak,Human-Human,0.547137761168677,2
Alex,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.137205030380104,2
Alex,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.262046204620462,2
Tak,Inferred,Human-Tak,0.137288621381485,2
Tak,Intended,Human-Gold Standard,0.280682000965096,2
Intended,Inferred,Tak-Gold Standard,0.097688926697859,2
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % borrowed styles from Jake's answer at
    % <http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301991/95441>
    \pgfplotsset{
%        % filter symbolic values
%        discard if not symbolic/.style 2 args={
%            % suppress LOG messages about the filtered points
%            filter discard warning=false,
%            x filter/.append code={
%                \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
%                \edef\tempb{#2}
%                \ifx\tempa\tempb
%                \else
%                    \def\pgfmathresult{NaN}
%                \fi
%            },
%        },
        % filter numerical values
        % (not needed here, but just for completeness)
        discard if not/.style 2 args={
            % suppress LOG messages about the filtered points
            filter discard warning=false,
            x filter/.append code={
                \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
                \else
                    \def\pgfmathresult{NaN}
                \fi
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={
                Human-Human,
                Human-Tak,
                Human-Gold Standard,
                Tak-Gold Standard
            },
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
        ]
            \foreach \i in {0,1,2} {
                \addplot+ [
                    discard if not={difficulty}{\i},
                ] table [
                    col sep=comma,
                    x=type,
                    y=kappa,
                ] {combined-kappas.csv};
                    \addlegendentryexpanded{\i}
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: You are right. Your answer was what I was looking for. I switched the x- and y-axes to workaround the overlapping tick labels.