# Conditional tests on string variables in tikzmath library

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, strings, tikzmath

Is it possible to test for strings in the tikzmath library? (E.g. if <variable>=<string expression> then foo)

I tried a naive test and it returned this error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `text' (in ' text== text').
```

MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
    let \str = text;
    if \str == \str then {%
        let \str = bird;
    };
}%
\str
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\test` command after the `\tikzmath` stuff? Even if the `\tikzmath` stuff went through, your snippet would cause an error.

Comment: As far as I know, the math library only recognizes integers, (real) numbers and coordinates as variable types, no strings.

Comment: Could you please tell us, for what you need the string comparison?

Comment: @Skillmon I could think of tons of applications if pgfmath were to support strings and, in particular, arrays. Strings could, for instance, refer to colors, and pgfmath may allow one to mix them beyond what is already possible.

Comment: @marmot the question was to determine whether there might be a feasible simpler approach (LaTeX3's `\tl_if_eq:nnTF` or something like that).

Comment: @Skillmon the application is I've written a mailmerge tikz graphic and I am using a custom command to set a bunch of tikz parameters  which change as I iterate through the records. Ideally I'd like to read in a string from the input *.dat file and depending on the value of string set different parameter values. I was hoping that tikzmath could cope with testing on strings as one can assign string values to variables using the let command: `let \c1 = blue; `

Comment: But then in further processing `tikzmath` thinks those are function names, not strings.

Comment: The xstring package has \IfStrEq which does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\tikzmath` feature doesn't allow string comparisons. You can use a different strategy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\strequal}[2]{\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}==0}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
    let \str = text;
    if \strequal{\str}{\str} then {%
        let \str = bird;
    };
}%
\str

\tikzmath{
    let \str = text;
    if \strequal{\str}{bird} then {%
        let \str = bird;
    };
}%
\str
\end{document}
```

Loading `pdftexcmds` ensures compatibility across engines.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expl3`'s `\tl_if_eq:nnTF` (which I made available outside of
`\ExplSyntaxOn` using `\cs_set_eq:NN`) inside a `tikzpicture`
(but not in `\tikzmath` as it would again try to evaluate your strings as
function names).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \tlIfEqnnTF \tl_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tlIfEqnnTF{foo}{bar}
    {\node at (0,0) {correct};}
    {\node at (0,0) {false};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base TeX solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcommand{\ifstrA}{}% reserve global names
\newcommand{\ifstrB}{}
\newcommand{\ifstr}[4]{% #1 = string A, #2 = stirng B, #3 = true, #4= false
  \def\ifstrA{#1}%
  \def\ifstrB{#2}%
  \ifx\ifstrA\ifstrB #3\relax
  \else #4\relax
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\ifstr{text}{text}{bird}{oops}
\end{document}
```