# \input inside \newcommand and macro parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, input, parameters, tikzmath

I would like to divide a list of parameters for a series of tikz graphics into a bunch of separate, named tex files.

Specifically: each parameter file should be loaded by an `\input` command which in turn is contained inside the definition of one cumulative `\newcommand`, see **setspecs-command.tex** below.

The `\newcommand` is itself loaded via another `\input` in the **main.tex** file.

I naively thought the `\newcommand` parameter numbers e.g. `#1` would work inside the inputted files, but I am getting the error message:

```
./parameters1.tex:5:
Illegal parameter number in definition of \tikz@math@marshal.
```

A related error message:

```
./parameters1.tex:1: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
```

comes from printing the parameter value inside the inputted file, e.g. by inserting the line:

```
Parameter file #1 was loaded.
```

before the `\tikzmath` environment in **parameters1.tex**.

Any thoughts on how to deal with `\newcommand` macro parameters inside a file loaded via `\input`?

Full MWE below:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

%%
%Courtesy of egreg, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415138
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\strequal}[2]{\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}==0}
\makeatother
%%

\input{setspecs-command}

\begin{document}
First graphic:\\
\setspecs{parameters2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \node at (0,0) {\var};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage

Then second graphic:\\
\setspecs{parameters1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \node at (0,0) {\var};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The file containing the definition of the setspecs command:

**setspecs-command.tex**

```
\newcommand\setspecs[1]{
    \input{parameters1}
    \input{parameters2}
    %... further files to be added as and when needed
}
```

Two examples of the parameter files below:

**parameters1.tex**

```
%Parameter file #1 was loaded.
%All parameter files will have the following overarching structure
\tikzmath{
    if \strequal{#1}{parameters1} then {
        \var = 111;
    };
}
```

**parameters2.tex**

```
\tikzmath{
    if \strequal{#1}{parameters2} then {
        \var = 222;
    };
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to have all of the specifications in different files? It’s not clear to me what you are trying to do but at first guess using `pgfkeys` looks to be a better approach. If you really do need to do it this way it would be simpler, and much more efficient, to have `\setspecs` input only the required file. Something like `\newcommand\setspecs[1]{\input{parameter#1}}`, although you might need some `\expandafter`s to make this work in practise. Will look tomorrow to see if no one else has answered.

Comment: @Andrew good point, the reason is I am trying to make the parameter files as user-friendly as possible for someone else to add or modify without getting into the guts of a complicated main file which generates a mail-merge tikz-graphic. I looked into `pgfkeys` (thanks!) from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114012) and unfortunately my basic issue persists. When I put the contents of the `\newcommand` definition inside an inputted file, parameters such as `#1` aren't recognized. But I am hoping someone here knows the right syntax, viz. your `\expandafter` comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with the following code in `setspecs-command.tex`, although I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish.

You need to add `\usepackage{catchfile}` to the document preamble.

```
\newcommand{\setspecs}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \CatchFileDef\temp{#1}{}%
  % double the #'s
  \toks0=\expandafter{\temp}%
  % define and evaluate
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\temp####1{\the\toks0}}\x\temp{#1}%
}
```

You may be interested in a much simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\strequal}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { 0==0~ } { 0==1~ }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setspecs}{m}
 {
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l__demodave_spec_tl {} { #1 }
  \cs_set:NV \__demodave_temp:n \l__demodave_spec_tl
  \__demodave_temp:n { #1 }
 }
\tl_new:N \l__demodave_spec_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
First graphic:\\
\setspecs{parameters2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \node at (0,0) {\var};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

Then second graphic:\\
\setspecs{parameters1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \node at (0,0) {\var};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The contents of `parameters1.tex` and `parameters2.tex` are exactly the same.

The idea is exactly the same as before, but the `expl3` code is more transparent with respect to “doubling the `#`’s”.

Comment: would I need to add some packages to the preamble to make this work?

Comment: @demodave Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to load `catchfile`.

Comment: @demodave I added a simpler version based on `expl3`.

Comment: the expl3 version works perfectly. I'm still having trouble with the first part of your answer and still getting the original error message. I added the two `\input{parameters_}` instructions in your version of the definition of `\setspecs` after the line `\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\temp####1{\the\toks0}}\x\temp{#1}%`. Was that what you intended?

Comment: @demodave No; that `\input` is unnecessary.

Comment: I see `\setspecs` does it all! That works also now.

Comment: is is possible to pass commands as arguments to your expl3 version of \setspecs? For the sake of argument, by adding something like `\newcommand{\testmacro}[1]{\#1} \setspecs{\testmacro{parameters1}}`? Is this one of those cases where understanding macro expansion and doubling the #'s is necessary, as the "typed-in" string `parameters1` from the MWE is not equivalent to what the command`\testmacro{parameters1}` expands to ?

Comment: @demodave Sorry, but I can't understand your aim.

Comment: My apologies, it is very unclear! Basically I've got a command `\FieldA` generated by another package (`textmerg`) in a loop (each iteration the text corresponding to `\FieldA` is picked up from a database) and I want to pass that text to `\setspecs` as in \setspecs{FieldA} rather thn `\setspecs{parameters1}` as in the MWE. Imagine the database is a long list of strings: `parameters1`, `parameters2`, `parameters1`, `parameters3`, etc.