# Filter several rows in addplot

Tags: pgfplots, filter

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301991/97882), it is possible to filter a row from a csv file, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{mycsvfile.csv}
levels,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99
0,11.0,22.0,33.0,44.0,55.0,66.0,77.0,88.0,99.0
1,11.1,22.1,33.1,44.1,55.1,66.1,77.1,88.1,99.1
2,11.2,22.2,33.2,44.2,55.2,66.2,77.2,88.2,99.2
3,11.3,22.3,33.3,44.3,55.3,66.3,77.3,88.3,99.3
4,11.4,22.4,33.4,44.4,55.4,66.4,77.4,88.4,99.4
5,11.5,22.5,33.5,44.5,55.5,66.5,77.5,88.5,99.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.append code={
            \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
            \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={Example},]
        \addplot[discard if={levels}{1}, mark=x, style=dashed] table[x=levels, y=55, col sep=comma]{mycsvfile.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

I would like to extend this functionality to something like `discard if in={levels}{1,3,5}` to simultaneously filter the rows 1, 3 and 5; that is passing a list intead of a single value.
I could obvisouly do `\addplot[discard if ={levels}{1}, discard if ={levels}{3}, discard if ={levels}{5}]` in this specific example but my goal is to make a generic feature `discard if in` for a list of any size.

What's the way to do this?

---

### Follow-up question:

Thanks very much to Steven for [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641589/97882) to the above question.

I have managed to create the `discard if not in` feature as:

```
discard if not in/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.append code={
        \readlist\mylist{#2}%
        \providecommand{\foundit}{0}
        \renewcommand{\foundit}{0}
        \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
            \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=\z pt
            \renewcommand{\foundit}{1}
            \else               
            \fi
        }
        \pgfmathparse{\foundit == 1? \pgfmathresult : nan}
    }
},
```

This seems a bit intricate and there probably exists a more elegant solution. I welcome any feedback on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I use the `listofitems` package to digest a comma separated list provided for the `#2` level-exclusion argument.  Then, I set up a `\foreachitem` loop to exclude each of those levels in the plot.  Here is how that is done in the `\pgfplotset`:

```
    x filter/.append code={
        \readlist\mylist{#2}%
        \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
          \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=\z pt
          \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
          \fi
        }
    }
```

Below is the MWE, in which levels 1, 3, and 4 are excluded, where the syntax used is `discard if={levels}{1,3,4}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{filecontents*}{mycsvfile.csv}
levels,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99
0,11.0,22.0,33.0,44.0,55.0,66.0,77.0,88.0,99.0
1,11.1,22.1,33.1,44.1,55.1,66.1,77.1,88.1,99.1
2,11.2,22.2,33.2,44.2,55.2,66.2,77.2,88.2,99.2
3,11.3,22.3,33.3,44.3,55.3,66.3,77.3,88.3,99.3
4,11.4,22.4,33.4,44.4,55.4,66.4,77.4,88.4,99.4
5,11.5,22.5,33.5,44.5,55.5,66.5,77.5,88.5,99.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.append code={
            \readlist\mylist{#2}%
            \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
              \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=\z pt
              \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
              \fi
            }
        }
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={Example},]
        \addplot[discard if={levels}{1,3,4}, mark=x, style=dashed] table[x=levels, y=55, col sep=comma]{mycsvfile.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]