# PGFPlots: how to achieve different colored bars with symbolic coordinates and a single \addplot command?

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
xmin=0,
xmax=290,
xlabel={Mentions},
ylabel={Title words},
symbolic y coords={
    {Devices},
    {Data},
    {Scheme},
    {Authentication},
    {Key},
    {Secure},
    {Lightweight},
    {Security},
    {Elliptic Curve Cryptography},
    {Wireless Sensor Networks},
    {Internet of Things},
    {Cryptography}
},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
]
\addplot coordinates {
(33,{Devices})
(47,{Data})
(49,{Scheme})
(52,{Authentication})
(61,{Key})
(68,{Secure})
(73,{Lightweight})
(78,{Security})
(111,{Elliptic Curve Cryptography})
(115,{Wireless Sensor Networks})
(246,{Internet of Things})
(257,{Cryptography})
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to color some bars of this chart in a different color. The fact that there is a single `\addplot` command along with that there are symbolic coordinates, makes it pretty difficult for me.

[image: bar chart]

Comment: maybe have a look if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on could help

Comment: Works, thanks! I cannot mark as solved, could you post it as an answer?

Comment: You're welcome! I suggested to mark the post as duplicate. This way your question will a signpost to help other users with the same problem to find a solution.

Comment: I want to color multiple bars, this suggestion only works for a single bar. Furthermore, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301985/filter-pgfplots-data-more-than-once-e-g-with-discard-if does not work for me either. Can you figure this out? https://pastebin.com/1etM75gr